# What determines whether a trait brought out through sexual selection is transmitted only to offspring of the same sex or of both sexes?

Tags: human-genetics, natural-selection, evolutionary-game-theory, sociality, sexual-selection

First of all, let me apologize for my amateurishness. I have no background in biology. Please bear with me.

My question relates to sexual selection, or specifically its most prominent manifestations:

- competition among males which is resolved through male conflict
- competition among males which is resolved through female decision

Let us postulate the traits that these two forms of selection might bring about, e.g., strength for the former case and attractiveness for the latter. Of course this may vary. Would I be right to say that whether this trait is passed on through the Y chromosome or whether is it passed on somewhere else (and therefore to both male *and* female offspring) is a question of probability? If so, what do the odds look like?

The aim of my question is really to understand how selection among men has changed the human species in general. It is well-known that aggression, charm, and paternal care are some traits that have evolved among men. But how would we go about measuring the impact of this selection upon the gene pool of the entire species?

Lastly, is there any literature based on evolutionary research that concerns my question in particular?

Comment: check out Monoamine Oxidase 1 (MOA1) gene. Very complex question to answer, there are a huge number of factors including things like hormone expression.

Comment: Whoops - MAO gene - apparently called MAOA, not sure where I got the 1 from.